# Can I show a hand-crafted flair-like widget on my website?

Tags: support, copyright, trademark, external-project

Can I show the following on my personal website/blog?

[image]

The white icon on the blue background is taken from [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/cheatsheet/), so I guess it's ok I use it.

Clicking on it redirects to [my account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5825294/), whereas hovering on it the little widget (I don't like [Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flair)) with my total reputation and badges pops up.

I've manually crafted it by picking colors and font from Stack Overflow (dark mode), but I'm not using any logo in it.

Is it ok?

From the [Trademark guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) I understand it is, because no mention is made of colors or fonts. Furhtermore, even if the colors of that widget are exactly those of Stack Overflow, given the nature of the widget (it pops up when hovering on the Stack Overflow icon which links to Stack Overflow itself), it's clear I'm not trying to

> mislead someone into thinking that your product was owned by, operated by, endorsed by, or in any way part of Stack Exchange Inc.

I'd say that, on the contrary, should I be so lucky that my blog becomes visible, I'd be giving more visibility to Stack Overflow (you're welcome).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no authority, and wanted to post a comment, but might as well turn it into an answer:
I don't see how it could be inappropriate. You're basically advertizing for SE. I think the flair is offered as a more accessible way to promote one's profile, not as an exclusive method to do so. Besides, linking to (almost) any page on the SE network is also completely fine, so why wouldn't this?

As long as you don't refer to it as flair, since that seems to (mockingly?) have been trademarked:

[image]

Comment: That's more or less what I think too. I wonder if some "authority" will ever answer. I suspect maybe those who could answer would never do, because this "lack of clarity" could just be "protective" for SE.

Comment: @Enlico That's a likely scenario. I thought I'd get a comment on the "mockingly" as well, but that might also very well be a source of uncertainty. Or maybe the legal authorities don't frequent the platform.